# How to get names of objects and then put them into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to put names (7, 8, 9) of each object from `combinationsFormController` into array.

The image comes from Firebug.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgf5ttdv/1/):

```
var combinationsFormController  = {
    prop1: {'prop1':7},
    prop2: {'prop2':8},
    prop3: {'prop2':9},
    1: {'prop1':7},
    2: {'prop2':8},
    3: {'prop2':9},
    7: {'prop1':7},
    8: {'prop2':8},
    9: {'prop2':9},
};

var arrProps=[];
for ( property in combinationsFormController  ) {
      if (combinationsFormController.hasOwnProperty(property))
      {
         console.log( property ); 
         arrProps.push(property)
      }
}
```

Comment: I can't reffer to them trough they name's because they are generated and on every page they have different names.

Comment: Where are they referenced by name? I just put an example.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers can use `Object.keys()` to create array

```
var arr = Object.keys(combinationsFormController);
```

For older browsers like IE<9 include the [polyfill found in MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)